# Python tkinter unintentionally creating two windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to build a simple calculator in Python 3 using tkinter. The calculator is split by a ttk notebook to divide functionality into groups, and each notebook frame should (once I get this fixed) be its own class. However, when I run the given code, I get two windows: one with the notebook + tabs but no content, and one that's entirely blank. What am I doing to initialize the second window, and how do I stop it/add the BatteryTab content to the battery tab? Thanks so much for your time!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

class PanelManager(tk.Tk):
    def __init__ (self):
        #initializing tkinter within initialization function
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Combat Robotics Calculator")
        self.panel_manager = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.add_battery_tab("Batteries")
            self.add_tab("Pulleys")
    self.add_tab("Drive System")
        self.add_tab("Weapon System")

    def add_tab(self, title):
        tab_frame = Frame(self.panel_manager)
        self.panel_manager.add(tab_frame, text = title)
        self.panel_manager.pack()

    def add_battery_tab(self, title):
        tab_frame = Frame(self.panel_manager)
        self.panel_manager.add(tab_frame, text = title)
        self.panel_manager.pack()
        battery_tab = BatteryTab()
        self.panel_manager.pack()

    def run(self):
        self.mainloop()


class BatteryTab(tk.Tk):
    def __init__ (self):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        #Capacity Calculator
        capacity_calcf = LabelFrame(self, text = "Battery Capacity Calculator").grid(column = 0)
        test = Label(capacity_calcf, text = "testing, testing, 1,2,3")
        #C Rating Calculator
        c_rating_calcf = LabelFrame(self, text = "Required C Rating Calculator").grid(column = 1)

root_window = PanelManager()
root_window.run()
```

Comment: You should have only a single instance of `Tk()` (or any class deriving from `Tk`) in your program.  `BatteryTab` should be a subclass of `Frame`, and you should be adding *that* (rather than an empty Frame) to `panel_manager` in `add_battery_tab()`.